# Rails ActionCable 6: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/cable' failed: WebSocket is closed due to suspension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, action

A vanilla Rails 6 application is giving this error:

```
"WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/cable' failed: WebSocket is closed due to suspension"
```

Actioncable Channel:

```
#app/javascript/channels/chat_channel.js
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("ChatChannel", {
  connected() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    console.log(data)
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
  }
});
```

Rails Controller:

```
 #app/controller/messages_controller:
 puts "*******Broadcasting"
 ActionCable.server.broadcast("chat_channel", content: @message.id)
```

ActionCable Channel:

```
# app/channele/chat_channel.rb
class ChatChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    puts "**** ChatChannel Subscribed"
    stream_from "chat_channel"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

Where did I slip up?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure in your **routes.rb** has this `mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'`

And in your **development.rb** file

```
config.action_cable.url = "ws://localhost:3000/cable"

config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [/http:\/\/*/, 
/https:\/\/*/]
```

Comment: That did not work for me. I'm getting the same error from CableReady.